# How to get 2 value form input array into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an input :

```
  <input type="text" name="input['.$opt_id.']">
```

and I can get `$opt_id` value on php side with :

```
foreach ($_POST['input'] AS $key => $value)
{
    $opt_id=$value;

}
```

but I want to get second value like this :

```
 <input type="text" name=input"['.$opt_id.']['.$lang_id.']">
```

How can I get `$opt_id` and `$lang_id`? I want to insert them on different columns in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have 2 entries having the same `opt_id` and `lang_id` then you can use a single key instead of 2:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="input[<?php echo "{$opt_id}_{$lang_id}"; ?>]" />
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['input'] as $optIdAndLangId => $value) {
    list($opt_id, $lang_id) = explode('_', $optIdAndLangId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within HTML markup you should insert `PHP` variables or any other `PHP` code in such way:

```
<input type="text" name="input[<?php echo $opt_id; ?>]">
...
<input type="text" name=input"[<?php echo $opt_id; ?>][<?php echo $lang_id; ?>]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This 
you can process the data with something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['input'] as  $key => $opt_id){
foreach($opt_id as $ans=>$lang_id){

    echo 'option id :'.$ans.' Lang Id : '.$lang_id;
}
}
```